# Diffeomorphism in Banach algebra

Tags: analysis, banach-algebras

Let $X$ be an algebra $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$. Let define $F:X\ni f \mapsto f(0)f \in X$

What is the biggest $r$ such that $F$ is $C^r$-diffeomorphism ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$F$ sends all functions vanishing at $0$ to the zero functions, and is therefore in no way shape of form a diffeomorphism. What is the sup of the empty set ?... ;-)

Comment: Ok, right. Let reformulate it. Let $A:=\{f\in X | f(0)>0\}$. We can define $F'$ by $F$ restricted to $A$. So, what in this case ?

Comment: I would ask which norm you endow $A$ with. I would rather call $G$ the restriction, to avoid any funny stuff. I would say that the differential of $G$ at a point $f$ of $A$ is the continuous linear map $h \mapsto f(0) h + h(0) f$. Of course, I would first observe that $G$ is injective : if $G(f) = G(g)$ then $f(0)^2 = g(0)^2$ showing that $f(0) = g(0)$ as we're in $A$, showing then that $f = g$. I would also observe surjectivity, plus continuous differentiability of the inverse. I would also observe that the class of $G$ is the one of $f\mapsto f(0)$.

Comment: Right, $F'$ is not good symbol ;-). In $A$ I use supremum norm from $X$ restricted to $A$.

Comment: Yeah, I implicitely used $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ in what I wrote in the above comment. Note that $f\mapsto f(0)$ is linear *and* continuous.